# django: update html dynamically when model is updated

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-channels

There is a Status model with instances saved in the database. There is a view generating the html code that displays these instances to the client.

Another process updates the values of the fields of these instances ('updates': read the instance from the database, change the values of some of the fields, and save the instances back to the database).

I would like the html report currently displayed to the client to be updated 'live' everytime the database has been updated.

I searched, but I am failing to determine the canonical way of doing this. It feels like I should use things like channels, data binding, WebsocketBinding. But the documentation (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/binding.html) is quite difficult to follow for a beginner and I could not find any example that would help me start.

It would be great, and possibly useful to many, to have a minimal example of this (not necessarily using WebsocketBinding if there are better ways of doing this)

Comment: If you want the web client to update incrementally of the backend/database, you might use a [SPA'ish style front-end (next.js is very popular now)](https://nextjs.org/) with a [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) backend.  This a REST/SPA pattern that a lot of places use with react.js and whatever your backend is written in ( perhaps django rest framework in your case).

Comment: If the updates to the status are on from web clients, I've used web sockets for these scenarios before.